# Does each post have its own visibility-time counter?

Tags: discussion

According to [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/):

> if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. "Worthwhile" here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

How is "visibility on the site" counted?

For example if I:

1. post a question/answer that gains +3 score on its 1st day
2. delete it on the 1st day
3. undelete 59 days later
4. delete it again on its 65th day since creation

Will it be considered "visible on the site for at least 60 days"?

---

If I:

1. post a question/answer that gains +3 score
2. delete it on its 32nd day since creation
3. undelete the post 7 days later, modify it (or not) and leave it
4. delete it again after another 32 days

Will it be considered "visible on the site for at least 60 days"?

---

Does each post have its own visibility-time counter? Or is it simple time difference between creation and deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your post has +3 score and 60 days already passed (regardless of being deleted or not, (un)deletions can happen multiple times during that period) and then you undelete (or don't touch if it was undeleted already), the post is considered  "visible on the site for at least 60 days" and thus you'll no longer loose rep if the post is deleted after.